# How can I increase subtitle size?

Tags: mass-effect-3

While recording I need the game volume turned down. This means that it can be hard to hear dialogue through the recording.

Is there any way to make the subtitles larger so they're easier to read without reducing the resolution?

Comment: If the aim is to have it possible for the viewer of what you're recording to understand the spoken words (either by reading the subtitles or actually just hearing them), could you have the game's speech volume set much louder that of music/effects/etc?

Comment: @DMA57361 I think his problem is there will be commentary over the game sound from other people

Comment: @Blem I assumed that is the case, but you'd either want people paying attention to commentary *or* the voice/subtitles; expecting people do pay attention to both at the same time (by talking over the top of the voice/subtitles) sounds like a bad idea / poor presenting to me.

Comment: @DMA57361 That could work, but there are other reasons I want them bigger.

Comment: I've noticed this is a problem with many PC games because the subtitle size doesn't scale with resolution...have you tried playing on a lower resolution?

Comment: Fair enough @RonanForman, I didn't expect it to really be a solution, but thought I'd at least suggest it in case it hadn't been considered.

Comment: Well there's certainly no options for it. I think your only option would be to edit the coalesed.bin or whatever, if even that has a setting for it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No.

**Explanation:** It is not possible to change the subtitle size in Mass Effect 3. It is possible to do so through coalesced, but you risk being banned. See the link in "Sources". People have been requesting this feature for a long time. It was one of the major gripes with Mass Effect 2. You can read GammaSquad's opinion [here](http://gammasquad.uproxx.com/2012/02/5-little-touches-we-really-hope-mass-effect-3-has) if your'e interested. If you want to do some coalsed modding, this is how to do it. **Be careful - you risk messing up game.dat and being banned for resource hacking. Proceed with caution.**

There are two tools that will accomplish this for Mass Effect 3. The first one is a little easier to use, however the second one is more powerful. You can download links for each below. Here is a comparison of the two tools:

### ME3 Coalesced Utility (Wenchy)

- Backs up previous previous versions of the bin file and can restore them if needed
- Easier to use then the second tool

**Tool Screenshot:**
[image]

[Tool Homepage](http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility/)

There are three versions of the tool with different capabilities. The comments section on the website provided is very active, and you can ask how to edit the subtitle size there.

Download Link for 1.1 (Direct Download): 
[Click Here](http://wenchy.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ME3Coalesced-1.1.zip)

### Mass Effect 3 Coalesced.bin Tool

- For the more technically inclined
- Exports file to editable JSON format
- Supports converting the JSON file back

[Tool homepage](http://blog.gib.me/2012/02/16/mass-effect-3-coalesced-bin-tool/)

This tool is more obscurely documented, and is a lot more work to set up. It does not backup the game files, if you want to do that you have to do it manually. It is several steps more, and overall I would recommend the other tool. But, your choice. You can try both and see which one you like better.

[Direct Link Download (current version)](http://mod.gib.me/masseffect3/coalesce-r46.zip)

### Conclusion

If your'e not convinced you want to do resource hacking, your only option is to change the screen resolution. Resource hacking has many disadvantages, you risk messing up your whole system. If you want this feature implemented by default, send a message to bioware. If enough people want it, they'll do it. So, you can try both tools and see which one you like better. I would recommend the first one because of ease of use, however, if you like the technical aspects the second one is great.

**Sources:**
[Mass Effect 3 Forums](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/1/topic/344/index/9670659/1#9688823)

[Gamespot - Coalesced Modding](http://www.gamespot.com/mass-effect-3/forum/lets-start-some-coalesced-modding-62160490/)

[Wenchy Project Homepage](http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility/)

[Resource.bin editor homepage](http://blog.gib.me/2012/02/16/mass-effect-3-coalesced-bin-tool/)

Comment: You say the change is possible with this, but am I missing where in the answer you actually say which setting to change?

Comment: Indeed, it's unclear what exactly should we change. I've carefully examined all options related to "subtitle", "font" or "size" and the only thing I found was `bioengine.ini: engine.engine/subtitlefontname = EngineFonts.SmallFont`, but changing it to `MediumFont`/`LargeFont` gains nothing. Google didn't help either. No progress so far.

Comment: Anyone finds a solution???

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but there's obviously no usual way to do that. Of course, you can do resource hacking afterall, but... I don't think it would be easy. I think it's a part of an engine, UE3, if I'm not mistaken, so, you should begin digging from this point. Also, you can try config file in Data folder, by I haven't seen anything useful to you.

Also I've found now this utility: http://wenchy.net/me3-coalesced-utility
It's used to edit the coalesced.bin file, which is here: \BIOGame\CookedPCConsole
There's A LOT OF ini files with settings, so, maybe you'll find what you need.
Anyway, it's a nice program, you can find a lot interesting here.